# Create Class dynamically at runtime

Tags: vb.net, generics, reflection, dynamic-class

I have a method like this: (this is a generic method, and `DYNAMIC_CLASS_TYPE` will be changed in situation to other situation)

```
Dim res = f.MyMethod(Of DYNAMIC_CLASS_TYPE)("select Id, Name from myTable")
```

I want to create a dynamic class, based on my query's columns and then pass the class instead of `DYNAMIC_CLASS_TYPE`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You should look into anonymous types. (And linq2SQL)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally succeeded in doing it. My Code is as:

```
 Public Shared Function CreateClass(ByVal className As String, ByVal properties As Dictionary(Of String, Type)) As Type

    Dim myDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    Dim myAsmName As New AssemblyName("MyAssembly")
    Dim myAssembly As AssemblyBuilder = myDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(myAsmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)

    Dim myModule As ModuleBuilder = myAssembly.DefineDynamicModule("MyModule")

    Dim myType As TypeBuilder = myModule.DefineType(className, TypeAttributes.Public)

    myType.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public)

    For Each o In properties

        Dim prop As PropertyBuilder = myType.DefineProperty(o.Key, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, o.Value, Nothing)

        Dim field As FieldBuilder = myType.DefineField("_" + o.Key, o.Value, FieldAttributes.[Private])

        Dim getter As MethodBuilder = myType.DefineMethod("get_" + o.Key, MethodAttributes.[Public] Or MethodAttributes.SpecialName Or MethodAttributes.HideBySig, o.Value, Type.EmptyTypes)
        Dim getterIL As ILGenerator = getter.GetILGenerator()
        getterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
        getterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field)
        getterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)

        Dim setter As MethodBuilder = myType.DefineMethod("set_" + o.Key, MethodAttributes.[Public] Or MethodAttributes.SpecialName Or MethodAttributes.HideBySig, Nothing, New Type() {o.Value})
        Dim setterIL As ILGenerator = setter.GetILGenerator()
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1)
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field)
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)

        prop.SetGetMethod(getter)
        prop.SetSetMethod(setter)

    Next

    Return myType.CreateType()

End Function
```

The return value of the function is a Type of my Custom Class.

Comment: Great little code snippet! One question though: Is there any specific reason you're using `GetType(Integer)` for your fields? Otherwise it'd probably be a good idea to apply [**the already mentioned change**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27499618).

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug. I think this line:

```
Dim field As FieldBuilder = myType.DefineField("_" + o.Key, GetType(Integer), FieldAttributes.[Private])
```

should look like this:

```
Dim field As FieldBuilder = myType.DefineField("_" + o.Key, o.Value, FieldAttributes.[Private])
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way is to use the System.Activator:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(YourType, ParramArrayOfYourVariablesForNEW)
```

So say I have a class (Test) that takes a single string in the initialization

```
Public Class Test
    Public Sub New(byval MyString as string)
...
```

You could create a new instance like this:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(gettype(Test),"My String")
```

Comment: the problem is that we do not have even that Test class and we want to create it runtime

Comment: You must have something somewhere that knows what it is. If you would rather get the type using a string, you can do this: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetType("WindowsApplication1.Test", True, True)`

Comment: I think my question was unclear and may be it is because of my bad english. Apologize for this. Your latest approach is not answer to my problem, because I need to CREATE the class at runtime. I mean I am going to introduce it's properties and fields and other elements all at runtime, and finally I am going to get it's type and do further operations. However I have reached an answer to this problem and I have shared it with all below. At the end I should thank you, for your great comments and tips and supports. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
Dim field As FieldBuilder = myType.DefineField("_" + o.Key, GetType(Integer), FieldAttributes.[Private])
```

must to be replaced with this:

```
Dim field As FieldBuilder = myType.DefineField("_" + o.Key, o.Value, FieldAttributes.[Private])
```