# Creating instance of dynamically created class and access its properties in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Few years ago in [create-class-dynamically-at-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956824/create-class-dynamically-at-runtime)

Has been explained how to dynamically create a class using CreateClass function. Function works fine, and I successfully enumerated properties of newly created class.

I know that I can create single instance of newly created class using

```
        Dim varNewType = CreateClass("clsTest2", TypeDict)
    Dim NewVar = Activator.CreateInstance(varNewType)
```

However, I don’t have I clue how to access its properties, how to set them or get their values.

Also, I need to create a list of this new created type. So please, if anyone has any idea, do share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would use Reflection to access members and, in the case of properties, their values.

Comment: Hi  jmcilhinney, I did realize that, but I’m not sure how to do that. If you would please put just few rows of code so I would know what objects and methods from Reflection I have to use. Also, if you have any Idea how to instantiate new list(of newtype), I would be very greatful.

Comment: You need to do your own research on Reflection first. Try what you think is required and then, if it doesn't work, post what you have and tell us what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using VB code, then its easy to access the methods and properties directly.

e.g.:

```
Dim varNewType = CreateClass("clsTest2", TypeDict)
Dim NewVar as object = Activator.CreateInstance(varNewType)
```

Then, in case it has a method Meth1, and a property Prop1, you can do thefollowing:

```
NewVar.Meth1(any params...)
Dim obj as object = NewVar.Prop1
```

No need for reflection or casting!

Comment: Hi Abusnake,
Thanks for your answer during weekend.
However, your solution doesn’t work here; this isn’t something I wouldn’t remember to try myself.
If you opened the link I had provided in question, you’d see that function made by someone smarter than me actually creates new type dynamically during runtime. At the design time, instance variable of that type is actually of type object. You cannot reach any of its properties through VS at the design time, because at that moment they are not yet created.
I need to know how to access those properties, and how to create list of that type.

Comment: At design time surly will not work. That will work at runtime. For design time, you need to add reference to that component in the visual studio. 

References->Add reference

Comment: @IvicaNesic, you would need to turn `Option Strict Off` and then you can use late-binding, which does allow you to refer to any member without knowing whether or not it will exist at run time. If it does exist at run time then it will work and if it doesn't then an exception will be thrown. The thing is, you still have to know the names of the members at design time. Do you know those names? Reflection not only lets you invoke the members but also lets you discover them, where late-binding requires you to know they will exist.

Comment: @Abusnake How to add a reference to something that does not exist in design time?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have a few excel books over 100M in size. I need to import data from them. I could open them, see the structure, and create classes representing every single sheet, but it takes days. Theoretically I do know names of properties, but then I don’t need Reflection. Practically, I know how to pick the sheet’s structure, and I do know properties’ names, but I don’t know how to access them from instance, and I don’t know how to make a list(of newtype). I’ll bow to your suggestion to dig in Reflection documentation, which would be the best.

Comment: You could create a `List(Of T)` using Reflection too but I'm not sure that it would be worth it. I'd probably suggest just creating a `List(Of Object)` if you're going to use Reflection to access the item properties anyway.